# make first item of recyclerview selected in master/detail flow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, master-detail

I'm trying to customize android studio's master/detail flow template for my project.

When running this template on a tablet, the master list of items (the RecyclerView) appears on left pane and a blank container appears on the right pane which is considered to be replaced with the detail fragment.
[Blank detail pane at startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUVxW.png)

I want to change this behavior so that instead of the blank container, detail of the **first item** of the RecyclerView to be appeared on the right pane at app start without clicking.

I tried to add the following code with no success:

Within onBindViewHolder method:

```
if (position == selectedPosition) {
    holder.mView.setSelected(true);
}
```

Within onClick(View v) method:

`selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();`

I read so many posts in stackoverflow but didn't find the answer.
Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to show on detailed panel, Make a function which takes position from ArrayList of your recyclerview and add details as per that position. And then call that function while adding adapter to recyclerview in Activty followed by holder.mView.setSelected(true). make these two custom functions in adapter and call them from your activity. it will work for sure.

Comment: Dear @ankur-mishra, your answer is not clear for me. Please explain it in more detail.